# r stop recursion but it isn't an infinite recursion

Tags: r, recursion, infinite

I designed a function in R that reads a matrix from `[x,y]` to `[0,0]` and it studied each value recursively.

For a small matrix I get good output, but for bigger ones (around 1000), R prints a message showing that I might have an infinite recursion problem, but it's not. I tracebacked and the code stopped around 100 iterations before finishing.

Is there a way to increment the number of allowed iterations before considering the function and infinite recursive one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's pretty hard to help you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the maximum recursive depth (e.g. to 10000), with:

```
options(expressions = 10000)
```

You can check the current value with:

```
getOption("expressions")
```

That being said, if you're iterating over all the elements in a 1000x1000 matrix, you might have a recursive call that is 1000000 deep, and you should probably restructure your code.

I guess it's somewhat amusing this question is being asked on StackOverflow?

Comment: (just because in C you would overflow your stack with recursion that deep)